# How can I measure shell latency when the time measuring commands also get stuck?

Tags: bash, shell, clearcase

- Some background and motivation

I'm working in a corporate that uses ClearCase for version control. In ClearCase, to work on a "branch" (stream) I have to enter a specific ClearCase shell for that stream.
The issue I've been having is that sometime these ClearCase shells are slow.

- Goal

I wanted to write a small script that would allow me to measure and print these performance hiccups. Once it's working I will use it to run other commands or send the information to the appropriate team.

- My attempt

I use "time" command to measure how long it would take to run "sleep 0.1" 200 times, which should take exactly 20 seconds, and based on how long it actually took, I do some things.

```
while true;
do
  /usr/bin/time -f "%e" -o saved_timing bash -c "for ((i=1; i<=200; i++)) do sleep 0.1 ; echo hello > /dev/null ; done" 
  elapsed_time=$(cat saved_timing)
  elapsed_time=${elapsed_time%.*}
  [ "$elapsed_time" -lt 23 ] && echo -n $elapsed_time || echo -ne "\033[1;31m$elapsed_time\033[0m"
  echo -n " "
  if [ "$elapsed_time" -gt 35 ] 
  then
    notify-send "`echo $pwv`"
    exit 0
  fi
done
```

- Example output

> 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 **23 24 25 25 25 25 24 30 25 42**

- The question

As you can see, it *sometimes* works, but in fact there are many instances where there's very obvious latency, but when there's finally a print on the screen, it just shows a normal "20".
I assume that this is because the "time" command itself got stuck, and not one of the "sleep" commands.

What can I do to solve this issue?

- Note

When I'm outside of the ClearCase shell I do not have these gaps in performance, and maybe I can run two different scripts, one in each shell, and have them communicate somehow. They both have access to my homedir, for instance.
However, I'm not quite sure how to leverage this idea and it it's the best approach.

Cheers.

Comment: What version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: Quite aside from other issues -- `sleep` does not offer real-time guarantees. It's allowed to sleep longer than you ask for without this being a bug, just as an artifact of how the OS scheduler works, and there's also some overhead common to all command executions that can eventually add up.

Comment: @VonC Normally 2.0.0.0, but we tried 3.0.0.1 and I had the same issue.

Comment: Also, `/use/bin/time` has more overhead (and more ways it can get "stuck") than the built-in `time`; the external version needs to fork off a child process, with the memory allocation that entails; needs to get the executable mapped into physical memory (if there's been enough pressure to force it out of the block cache this may mean going to disk and thus being subject to IO latency), etc etc.

Comment: Similarly, `elapsed_time=$(cat saved_timing)` is quite slow because it's forking off an external process to run `cat`. Consider the bash extension `elapsed_time=$(<saved_timing)`, or `read -r elapsed_timing <saved_timing` if there's only one line, etc. to get your results back in with less overhead.

Comment: Anyhow -- if I were faced with the problem described here, I would install sysdig and use that to get a trace describing which specific syscalls it is that get stuck.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your comments. I'm trying to rewrite this whole part to use "time" and not "/usr/bin/time" and stay away from the whole "write to file and then read from file" approach. I did it because I found it difficult to pipe the time output to other commands like 'grep' and 'cut' so I did it in a weird way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I will look into sysdig. Meanwhile, do you think this is better than "time"?

  SECONDS=0
  for ((i=1; i<=200; i++))
  do
    sleep 0.1 ; echo hello > /dev/null ;
  done 
  elapsed_time=$SECONDS

Comment: Re: piping or storing output of the built-in `time`, see [BashFAQ #32](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032). And no, I definitely don't consider the above better than `time`.

Comment: ...also, think about replacing ```notify-send "`echo $pwv`"``` with `notify-send "$pwv"` -- unless you _want_ the side effects of the unquoted expansion to `pwv` (performing globbing and word-splitting before passing content to `echo`). To avoid those you'd need more quotes -- `notify-send "$(echo "$pwv")"` is the modern syntax, ```notify-send "`echo \"$pwv\"`"``` is how it'd look to use the legacy/pre-modern syntax more correctly -- but the command substitution is probably pointless anyhow unless you want some behaviors that are... very rarely intentional.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why isn't the `SECONDS` method better? I figured that the only way for the eventual print to show 20 when the iteration took longer is if the assignment of `SECONDS=0` took the brunt of the latency, which seems less likely to me than a command like `time` being subject to latency

Comment: The big problem with `SECONDS` is that it's an integer; you're rounding everything off to the nearest second, and also losing information about what _kind_ of time was taken; the user/system/wall-clock distinction is important in the kind of situation we're looking at here, as it can help to distinguish between the process under test being slow itself, vs some requests it makes of the OS kernel being slow, vs something on the other end of an IPC connection being slow. And if you're using the _built-in_ `time`, it's already part of bash itself, so overhead is minimal.

Comment: @NimrodWeinberg To my knowledge, there is no CC 2 or 3, only 7, 8 or 9.x. What shell are you using for your Unix/Linux command?

Comment: @vonc I suspect this is HCL VersionVault 2.0.0.0, which is close to ClearCase 9.0.2.(patch intervals are offset by 3 months or so...).

Comment: @NimrodWeinberg, Need to verify assumptions and ask a couple of questions. 1) by "cleartool shell" do you mean the shell spawned by "cleartool set view" or the shell reached by using.! from a cleartool prompt, or something else entirely? 2) what are the contents of the PATH environment variable at the time this script runs? I'm looking to know if VOB directories are in the path. 3) What are the EXACT OS and clearcase / VersionVault versions? 3) what is the current working directory when you run that script.

Comment: @NimrodWeinberg, a couple of other things: 1. Where is the license server (cleartool hostinfo - long)? 2. Where is the view in relation to the client host? 3) is the async license support enabled? (cleartool getlog -inquire will tell you there is a "lad" log if so)

Comment: Also, this sounds AWFULLY familiar. Is there an HCL support case associated with this question?

Comment: You know I know you know :)

1. The shell from `cleartool setview <viewname>`
2. `echo $PATH | grep vob` yields nothing
3. SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP5 Release: 12.5
4, 5, 6 I can answer that over email.
7. lad Asynchronous License log
8. Yes. This script is in response to needing to run a command immediately after a slowness episode, but I don't have privileges to run the script, and the people with permission don't know when there's slowness. I thought I'd help them with a script.

Comment: Found some support case(s), not just ones where you're attached. One case was script specific where executables didn't start "after sourcing the environment setup script." At one point we were doing something like an "strace -fCvTtto /tmp/sleeptrace  sh -c sleep 10," and finding that -- in that case -- the PATH environment variable had something like 20 VOB paths in it... IN FRONT OF /bin and /usr/bin... I don't recall similar searches for libraries in those straces. But that can give you an idea of what the shell startup is doing, and then the child process startup.

Comment: @NimrodWeinberg -- forgot to add the notify in my update.